# Foam and bubbles

Tags: yeast, mash, foam

my first mash.  Combined all the ingredients in a "recipe" I followed. Added the yeast and it started working rather quickly. My airlock is due to come in the mail in 2 days. So I did the whole balloon/condom topper until it arrives. But after I put it on top and poked the small holes for the gas release the balloon still filled with foam and thankfully I was still awake. I removed the balloon and cleaned it well. Put a new one on same thing. My yeast is going crazy. Did I do something wrong? The foam wants to overflow.

Comment: Do I need to add more yeast after it's done foaming over? It's till foaming like crazie.

Comment: So I don't need to add anything after it's done spewing foam right? I made a few airlocks since mine still have not come in yet. And all seems fine. No over flowing just a bubble here and there.  the cold corn mash didn't over flow but bubbling fine on the air lock. I'm doing gallon mashes. As this is my first attempt I wanted to try a few recipes. I know gallons arent the best way since I won't get much but before I make a big batch I want to find one I like. Doesn't seems like there's many ladies here. I like vodka and rum and using bakers yesterday and suggestions on recipes guys?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a normal healthy fermentation.  You did nothing wrong.  In the future you could get a piece of sanitized tubing larger enough to fit in the opening of the carboy and jam it in there.  Then direct all that foam into a pitcher or bucket of water at the side of the carboy.  That's called a blow off.

But what you did was fine.  Once the foaming slows down it will still be fermenting. That will be a good time to put the airlock on.  Not before or you'll be cleaning the airlock of foam too.

Comment: Pro tip: with a blow-off tube like this, make sure the bucket of water and the end of the blow off tube below the carboy, or at the same height. If it's above the carboy, you could end up siphoning whatever's in the bucket into the beer should the pressure in the carboy drop.

Answer (score 0):

Next time try cooling down to under 70°F/20°C and letting it ferment in a cooler place, say around 64-65F/17°C - that will reduce the amount of foam produced since the yeast work slower. You will probably also get cleaner tasting beer as a result.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer brewchez provided, here is something I have done in these situations: Get a [3-piece airlock](https://www.midwestsupplies.com/airlock-3-piece-type.html?utm_medium=feeds&utm_source=google&gdftrk=gdfV24959_a_7c1306_a_7c6184_a_7c6005&gclid=COeSnYH32rwCFc5DMgodhEkArg) and some 1/2" tubing and fashion it like so:

[image]

I fill the bucket with bleach or star san.